# What is better - more data receivers or more threads per consumer?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

In Spark Streaming documentation they suggest to parallelize the data receiving ([link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/streaming-programming-guide.html#reducing-the-batch-processing-times)). They suggest an example to create multiple Data Receivers:

```
val numStreams = 5
val kafkaStreams = (1 to numStreams).map { i => KafkaUtils.createStream(...) }
```

Doing that you will get 5 cores to receive data luckily in 5 different machines. But in terms of performance, why is this option better than having a Data Receiver with 5 threads? (For instance for machines with more than 5 cores)

```
val numThreads = 5
val topicList = Map("topic1" -> numThreads)
val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, kafkaParams, topics, ...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case where we create 5 consumers, we are distributing, parallelizing the work over the cluster. Any computations done over that data will be potentially done over different nodes in parallel.

When the messages are consumed by one receiver using n threads, all messages are received on one machine. Any attempt to parallelize that workload will result in shipping data over the network to another executor that will cost time and resources.

At high loads, distributing I/O over several physical hosts is the only way to handle the throughput. In this case, you need to make sure that the consumers are scheduled on different physical nodes. Spark v1.5 has an [improved scheduling mechanism](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8882) to help with that.

Comment: In the second paragraph you refer to an scenario where is just one consumer with many threads, right? The start seemed confusing to me (non english speaker here hehehe).

Comment: Would that improvement in Spark v1.5 help with the issue that is mentioned here? http://markmail.org/message/257a5l3oqyftsjxj

Comment: @Marco my bad: Typo "[T]hen -> [W]hen" lead to a very weird sentence. I've corrected that.